# Combinatorics: choose 5 out of 10 colored balls

Tags: combinatorics

I usually don't have any problems thinking about combinatorics but this problems answer doesn't seem correct.

There are $5$ black balls, $1$ red, $1$ green, $1$ blue, $1$ yellow and $1$ white.
In how many ways can you pick $5$ balls?

The answer is $2^5$ but why?
I'm comparing it with a lock with $4$ integers, which has the number of combinations of $10^4$.

Anyone got any explanations?

Comment: For each of the non-black colours, you can either pick or not pick that ball; then pick from the black balls until you have 5 balls in total.

Answer (score 3):

You can get $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, or $5$ black balls.

- Clearly, there is just **one** way to get $0$ black balls: you just get all the colored balls.
- There are **five** ways of getting only $1$ black ball: you could leave out the red, or the green or the blue, or the yellow, or the white ball.
- There are $5!/2!3!$ ways of getting $2$ black balls. You can leave out any combination of 2 out of the 5 colored balls.
- There are $5!/n!(5-n)!$ ways of getting $n$ black balls. (Did you get why?)

In the end, summing all the ways you can get 5 balls:

$$\frac{5!}{0!5!} + \frac{5!}{1!4!} + \cdots + \frac{5!}{5!5!}=2^5$$

Since the sum of the $n$-th row of Pascal's triangle is $2^n$.

Comment: Yea, I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the set of ways to pick balls, there is either a red or none; and if there are no red balls, then there must be a black ball. Similarly for all other non-black colours.

Consider the five pairs of balls: red and black, green and black, blue and black, yellow and black, and white and black.

The number of ways to pick $5$ balls is the same as the number of ways to pick one ball from each of the five pairs: $2^5$.